# Broken GTK theme after upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: gtk

I upgraded my Ubuntu to version 18.04.1 LTS and everything works fine except that windows don't appear correctly as you can see in the screenshot :

- padding and borders are missing on windows menu and buttons
- terminal background is now grey (was black)

Any idea how to qualify this problem and how can I solve it?
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJu9N.jpg)

Thanks,

EDIT: I did `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to update some packages and now all packages are at their latest version but for some reason the problem is still here.

```
bragar@bragar-Lenovo-ideapad-710S-13ISK:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] Mot de passe de bragar : 
Atteint:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Réception de:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83,2 kB]                              
Réception de:3 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                              
Atteint:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu bionic InRelease                             
Atteint:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                    
Réception de:6 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                      
414 ko réceptionnés en 1s (367 ko/s)                          
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Tous les paquets sont à jour.
bragar@bragar-Lenovo-ideapad-710S-13ISK:~$
```

GTK version :

```
$ apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
libgtk2.0-0:
  Installé : 2.24.32-1ubuntu1
  Candidat : 2.24.32-1ubuntu1
 Table de version :
 *** 2.24.32-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgtk-3-0:
  Installé : 3.22.30-1ubuntu1
  Candidat : 3.22.30-1ubuntu1
 Table de version :
 *** 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is fixed after I installed Gnone Tweak tool and select the default theme (was a broken GTK Flatabulous).

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```